# Help debugging sshfs error: "fusermount3: mount failed: Operation not permitted"

Tags: sshfs, nixos, fuse, nix

I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to debug where the issue lies but am unable to find a fix. I am working on a 32bit CentOS system and have installed sshfs and fuse via nix.

When I try to run sshfs using `sshfs -v root@host:/ ~/mnt/host` it just returns `fusermount3: mount failed: Operation not permitted`. `lsmod` shows fuse is there.

I have digged into the first three pages of google on the error but none of the advice worked, any idea where I should be looking?

Comment: Check if you have ``rw`` permissions on ``/dev/fuse``.